# Load remote String content into arraylist in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

On the server side I have a php script that connects to my mysql database and echo's string based on myurl.com/connection.php?id=22 where the 22 in the example obviously is the id for the string I want.

In my Android application I want to fill an arraylist with like 100 strings, but I am unsure how to do so, and what the best approach for doing it is.

As I understand I need to use asynctask to free the main thread from the process, and I have also looked at httpget although I am not sure if that is the only way of loading remote server content?

Answer (score 0):

so from the my sql database the string values are returned ? right ?

the best way to do it is make the output from the server in json format and in your andriod app read the stream from the page and using json read fuctions and add the contents to your arralist using list . add() ; function...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try out that approach